# Pandas Metadata Properties Not Passed to Groups of a Groupby Object

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,1]})
df._metadata += "name"
df.name = "The Name"

groups = df.groupby(by="B")
for id, group in groups:
    print(group.name)
```

The `print` function will throw an `AttributeError`.

Now, I would need to somehow pass the metadata to each individual group. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this notation (`df['COLNAME'] = 'VALUE'`) to add new columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,1]})
df['_metadata'] = "name"
df['name'] = "The Name"

groups = df.groupby(by="B")
for id, group in groups:
    print(group.name)
```

Output:

```
0    The Name
2    The Name
Name: name, dtype: object
1    The Name
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still access it from `df`, no?

```
# ...
for id, group in groups:
    print(df.name)
```

You could also then assign to each group if you need to do that for whatever reason:

```
# ...
for id, group in groups:
    group.name = df.name
```